# .getVersion() not storing browser version number

Tags: java, selenium, browser, selenium-webdriver, version

Trying to write the browser name and version number to the console with the following code:

```
DesiredCapabilities test = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer()
String browserName = test.getBrowserName();
String ver = test.getVersion();

System.out.println(browser name + " v: " + ver);
```

This would print the following:

> internet explorer v:

the ver doesn't hold any version number - any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting your capabilities and then using the object of `getCapabilities()` print your browserName and browserVersion. Try this way -

```
Capabilities cap = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities();
String browserName = cap.getBrowserName();
String ver = cap.getVersion();
System.out.println(browser name + " v: " + ver);
```

Your code is for getting the capabilities of IE Driver only and this one is universal to all drivers. Hope this helps.